# Find all directories in directory and return only name

Tags: vb.net, directory, .net

I want to find all directories in one directory in vb.net.

I found one script:

```
For Each Dir As String In Directory.GetDirectories(FolderName)
    ComboBox3.Items.Add(Dir)
Next
```

It returns full name of path, but I want it to return only name of path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest way is to use `System.IO.DirectoryInfo`:

```
    For Each Dir As String In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(FolderName)
        Dim dirInfo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(Dir)
        ComboBox3.Items.Add(dirInfo.Name)
    Next
```

(Obviously, you could parse it manually and extract out the text following the final '\', but I believe that the above is more readable)

Comment: Vote Up requires 15 reputation

Comment: @ad48 You can still accept answers; it keeps the site workable, and helps avoid a multitude of questions listed as 'unanswered'.

Comment: Instantiating a new System.IO.DirectoryInfo() for each time seems overkill. That's an expensive operation, even though you already have all of the info that you need, in the string...

Comment: @LynnCrumbling It is overkill, you're right. As I said in the answer, that's just for readability.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way would be using `String.Replace` to remove `FolderName` from the beginning of the directory full name.

```
For Each Dir As String In System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(FolderName)
    ComboBox3.Items.Add(Dir.Replace(FolderName, String.Empty))
Next
```

Comment: Work,but at first character is \

Answer (score 1):

Use this to get only the directory name:

```
dirName = IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(fullPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
    For Each d As String In IO.Directory.GetDirectories(FolderName)
        'IO.Path.GetFileName
        'The characters after the last directory character in path.
        ComboBox3.Items.Add(IO.Path.GetFileName(d))
    Next
```

This takes advantage of the fact that you have a list of directories and what IO.Path.GetFileName actually does.

Comment: I think you meant 'GetDirectoryName'.

Comment: No, I meant GetFileName.  Read the documentation or try the code.

Comment: MSDN states "Returns the file name and extension of the specified path string." The question asked for a list of directories, not a list of files. The code does work, but that doesn't discount that you are using a method in a manner it wasn't designed for.

Comment: Read the whole thing to find out what it actually returns.  Not well named, but...

Comment: "Return Value
Type: System.String
The characters after the last directory character in path..."

Comment: Yes, I know. It happens to work for directories. It's just not designed for it (it can't handle trailing / characters, for example); that's what GetDirectoryName is for.

Comment: As it turns out the behavior of GetDirectoryName is different if the trailing character is / or \.  AFAIK System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories returns properly formatted strings.

Answer (score 0):

```
  For Each Dir As String In Directory.GetDirectories(FolderName)
        ComboBox3.Items.Add(IO.Path.GetFileName(Dir))
  Next
```