# when using Directory.GetDirectories Method is there a way to only return the name of the directories?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to populate a combobox with the names of the folders in a directory.
When I use `Directory.GetDirectories Method`, it returns the whole path.

For example, given:

```
C:\Projects\test
C:\Projects\test1
C:\Projects\test2
```

I would like to obtain only the folder names as follows:

```
test
test1
test2
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find all directories in directory and return only name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17568166/find-all-directories-in-directory-and-return-only-name)

Comment: In general, if you want to do some sort of operation that involves directories or file names, you should start by reviewing the available functions in `System.IO.Path`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could try something like this :

```
System.IO.Path.GetFileName(directory);
```

This is meant for files, but should also work with directories, `System.IO.Path` would consider it a file without extension so it would work.